# Is the function $g(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}{(\tanh(nx))}$ well defined?

Tags: limits, functions

I got the functions:
$$g_n(x) : \mathbb R \rightarrow\mathbb R:x \mapsto\tanh(nx)$$
$$g(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}{g_n(x)}$$

And I would like to show that $g$ is well defined, as well as for which $n\in \mathbb N,x\in \mathbb R$ is $g_n$ continuous and where $g$ is continuous.

I tried to show that $g(x)$ is a correctly defined function by showing that the $\lim_{n\to\infty} \tanh(nx) $ exists. However, if one looks at the corresponding series with $$\tanh(nx)=\frac{\sinh(nx)}{\cosh(nx)}$$ I do not see how this should converge at all? The only thing I see is that I am dividing two series, which, as $n$ goes towards infinity just have infinite summands as well.

How do I solve this in a correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so as you stated above we have that
$$
\tanh(x) = \frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)}.
$$
As you probably know we also have that
$$
\sinh(x)= \frac{\exp(x)-\exp(-x)}{2}, \quad \cosh(x)= \frac{\exp(x)+\exp(-x)}{2}.
$$
Using this we get that
$$
\tanh(x)= 1 - \frac{2}{\exp(2x)+1}, \quad \text{for all} \ x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Now we distinguish three cases: first let $x=0$. Then
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \tanh(nx) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \tanh(0) =   \tanh(0) = 1- \frac 22 =0
$$

Next, if $x<0$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \exp(2nx)=0 $, therefore
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \tanh(nx) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1 - \frac{2}{\exp(2nx)+1} = 1-2 =-1, \quad x<0.
$$
Finally, if $x>0$ then then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \exp(2nx)=\infty $, therefore
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \tanh(nx) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1 - \frac{2}{\exp(2nx)+1} = 1-\frac2\infty =1, \quad x>0.
$$
To sum up:
$$
g(x)= \begin{cases}-1 & x<0, \\
\ 0& x=0, \\
\ 1& x>0
 \end{cases}.
$$
In particular, $g$ is not continuous at zero.

Comment: Just a question: Do you have an idea how I would prove that the limit as $n$ goes towards infinity of $exp(2nx) = 0$ without using $e$? The way we defined $exp$ so far was by using a power series and I am not sure, whether I can use the fact that $exp(x)$ is always positive and monotone...

Comment: it easy to show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \exp(x)=\infty$ using power series. Then simply use l'Hospital's rule and the fact $\lim_{x \rightarrow-\infty} \exp(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1} {\exp(x)}$